# Angular 2 Component View - partially sync'd

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms

I'm hitting a problem whereby HTML elements not prefixed with `md` such as `<input mdInput>` remain sync'd with their underlying model, but those that are, such as `<md-select>` and `<md-checkbox>` are **not** updated, and therefore get out of sync with the underlying model.

**NOTE** - I can't recreate the problem in this [this Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/m4qmoCAOykidfLxpTeGR/) - but the plunker is *very* similar to my code running locally. I don't know how to investigate this further, so I'm trying here for ideas as much as anything.

**TL,DR** - I understand a component view may get out of sync with its underlying model, but what would cause **some** UI elements (`<input>`) to remain in-sync while others do not (`<md-checkbox>` and `<md-select>`)?
 The latter are only sync'd when an event (`mouseover`, `hover`, `click`, etc) triggers change detection?

**Details** - One clue could be that using `[(ngModel)]` on md-checkbox caused the checkbox to become out-of-sync:

```
<!-- Checkbox wasn't updated in UI until change detection triggered. -->
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked" name="checked"></md-checkbox>
```

However, changing this to bind to the value, ensured the checkbox remained in sync (see the addition of `checked="{{node.checked}}"` in the following:

```
<!-- This always remains in-sync. -->
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked" name="checked" checked="{{node.checked}}">
```

So I *assume* a similar issue is affecting `<md-select>` only I can't bind directly to the value, and so it remains out-of-sync.

See [this Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/m4qmoCAOykidfLxpTeGR/) for an example of a recursively rendered component displaying a JSON 'tree'. Each JSON object (i.e. node) is comprised of four fields:

1. `title:string`
2. `checked:boolean`
3. `types:[]`
4. `children:[]`

`title`, `checked` and `types` fields are just dummy values, but have been deliberately chosen to represent different material design form fields:

1. `<input mdInput>` - simple.
2. `<md-checkbox>` - complex.
3. `<md-select>` - complex.

The `children` field is how the 'tree' is formed. Leaf nodes will not have any `children`, but parent nodes will

Leaf node: `{'title': 'L1-A', 'checked': false, 'types': ['NUMBER']}`

Non-leaf node:

```
{
  'title': 'L1-A',
  'checked': false,
  'types': ['NUMBER'],
  'children': [
    'title': 'L2-A',
    'checked': false,
    'types': ['NUMBER'],
  ]
}
```

I've hard-coded two JSON objects representing a starting state and an updated state:

```
export class Tree {

  treeStart:any = {
    'title' : 'L0',
    'checked': false,
    'types': ['NUMBER']
    'children' : [
      {'title': 'L1-A',
      'checked': false,
      'types': ['STRING']
        'children' : [
          {'title': 'L2-A','checked': false,'types': ['INTEGER']}
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  treeUpdated:any =  {
    'title' : 'L0-UPDATED',
    'checked': true,
    'types': ['NUMBER']
    'children' : [
      {'title': 'L1-A-UPDATED',
      'checked': true,
      'types': ['NUMBER']
        'children' : [
          {'title': 'L2-A-UPDATED','checked': true,'types': ['NUMBER']}
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  tree:any;

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.tree = this.treeStart;
  }
}
```

You can probably see the JSON trees are identically structured but with different titles. `checked:false` to start and `checked:true` for updated. `L0` is the root node.

Two Angular 2 components render the JSON:

- `tree-component.ts / tree-component.html`
- `node-component.ts / node-component.html`

`tree` kicks things off by rendering a single `node`. `node` then recursively renders itself for any `children`.

Root node (Tree) rendered with `tree-component.html`:

```
<md-card>
  <app-node [node]="tree"></app-node>
</md-card>
```

`node-component.html` recursively renders:

```
<!-- Checked -->
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="node.checked" name="checked"></md-checkbox>

<!-- Title -->
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Title"
  #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="node.title"
  name="title" value="{{node?.title}}">
</md-input-container>

<!-- Types -->
<md-select placeholder="Type" multiple="true"  color="accent [(ngModel)]="node.types">
<md-option *ngFor="let type of allTypes" [value]="type.value {{type.display}}</md-option>
</md-select>

<!-- Recursive rendering -->
<md-card *ngFor="let child of node?.children">
  <app-node *ngIf="child" [node]="child"></app-node>
</md-card>
```

An update and reset button are added to tree-component.html since update and reset apply at the Tree level.

```
<button md-raised-button (click)="update()">Update</button>
<button md-raised-button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Clicking the `update` button in the [Plunker example](https://embed.plnkr.co/m4qmoCAOykidfLxpTeGR/) loads the updated tree after an arbitrary timeout (to mimic an API call):

```
update(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.apiCallback();
  }, 2000);
}

apiCallback(): void {
  this.tree = this.treeUpdated;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

The amount of JSON being rendered can get very large, and the subsequent tree may be very deep and/or wide. For this reason, the node component uses the [change push detection strategy](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-node',
  templateUrl: './src/node.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Node implements OnInit {
   /* Node implementation goes here. */

}
```

Tree component uses default change detection.

I'm hitting a problem whereby 'simple' material design form fields such as `mdInput` always remain in sync with the model, but 'complex' form fields such as `md-select` are not updated until an event occurs.

Comment: have you tried using [(ngModelChange)]="node.checked" instead of [(ngModel)] ?

Comment: Tried, but it didn't keep the `<md-checkbox>` sync'd, so reverted to `checked="{{node.additionalProperties}}"`. Also, I can't use `[(ngModelChange)]` on `<md-select>`.